# Xcode 6 auto-layout same spacing

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, uistoryboard

I have a problem with auto-layout in xcode 6. I am doing 4xUITextField which are next to each other. I set up constraints for every UITextField, but I don't know how to set up these fields on horizontal center and with same spacing. How can I set up these spacing?

Also I am doing app for iphone/ipad with portrait mode only. For better imagination I inserted screenshot.

Thank you for replies.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to add even spacing between them is to add blank spacer views between them and set the spacer views' widths equal. Make sure each view has zero spacing to the next view on either side. It would look something like this:

```
[field 1][spacer 1][field 2][spacer 2][field 3][spacer 3][field 4]
```

Then set the width of `spacer 1` equal to the width of `spacer 2` and the width of `spacer 2` equal to the width of `spacer 3`.